# PHP 5.4.4 Authentification HTTP on Debian

Tags: php, http, authentication, nginx

I had the opportunity to use global variables for the HTTP authentication on a PHP script (PHP_AUTH_USER and PHP_AUTH_PWD) and but it does not work on my Debian server with PHP 5.4.4.

Here's what I used before: http://www.php.net/manual/fr/features.http-auth.php

I'm looking, I can not find solutions. FYI, I'm on NGINX.

Thank you to you

Vince

Comment: What, in particular, is not working? Browser doesn't give a popup? Global auth variables show wrong values?

Comment: I call my url : user:password@nomdomaine.com/script.php and PHP_AUTH_USER and PHP_AUTH_PWD are not initialized

Comment: The manual (and user comments there) list several scenarios where this will not work ^- have you checked them all?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things you can try:

1. Make sure you're using `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and not `$PHP_AUTH_USER`. The second form stopped being the default in 4.2.0 and was [removed completely in 5.4](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.registerglobals.php).
2. As a sanity check, try `var_dump($_SERVER)` and see if other server variables are being set.
3. Update this post with the code you're using to send the auth request headers and to fetch the PHP_AUTH_USER and PHP_AUTH_PWD values, maybe there's something else afoot.

Comment: Yes I use $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']. in vardump of $_SERVER, I see $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] but it's empty... I will test with module nginx http_auth_request_modul not in default on nginx. For security, I don't want use a .htpassword